# Request focus on the selected edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, focus

In my layout I have several edittexts for title, date, time etc. one above the other. The problem is whatever field I click the first edittext gets focused (if I want to fill date edittext first I have to click it, the keyboard shows with focus on first edittext and then I have to click again date edittext to be able to fill it). How can I make it focus the edittext which I clicked? I tried to requestFocus on the edittext after clicking but nothing is changed.

[image]

Each edittext looks like this in XML

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawablePadding="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/tab_indicator_text"
        android:hint="Title">
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="25sp"
        android:layout_height="25sp"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:src="@drawable/tv" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Please, provide the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Steps you need to follow.

1) If your **EditText** is vertically arrange then, first EditText should have  in layout.xml.
2) Give proper **input type** for each **EditText** like for example **NameEditText** input type would be "**textPersonName**". Based on you input type **keyboard** will change and **cursor** will be **move** to next edittext.
3) You can also implements **FocusChangeListener** for each EdiText, if want to do any operation based on focus changes.

Try Once hope it will work :) **GlbMP**

Answer (score 0):

I don't really get your question but try this. If its already setting a particular view on focus and you want to change that you can Set both **android:focusable** and **android:focusableInTouchMode** to true and call **requestFocus** to the particular view you want to request focus on.

Otherwise, if its that you have requested focus on all your editText it will probably listen to the touch and set focus on the firstView since it cant set focus on all your views at the same time. So you can remove all the requestFocus calls in the editText and try again without them. They should work as you say.

If thats not what you mean too, then try adding a click listener to editText you want to setFocus on and call requestfocus. Thats it. Hope it helps..

Comment: I hope my last edit makes the question clearer. I tried your suggestions but still whatever I click title edittext is focused. Also, I don't know if it matters but the keyboard appears at the end ot the listview and I have to scroll up to see the fields.

Comment: @Nikola Add this to your manifest let me see **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"** to the particular activity

Comment: @Nikola you do this if you want to hide the keyboard when you enter the activity **android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"** in the particular activity tag in your manifest